# Access Cookies in React outside of components

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I am building a react project and have set up my axiosInstance so that the jwt access token is used automatically in axios requests.  However, when the token expires I would like to automatically refresh the token.  I added react-cookie to my project but to use the hooks I need to do so within a component.  I am using a separate axiosInstance file however, so I need to get the cookies from a utility file.

Is there a way to do this with react-cookie or another package?

Comment: create a response interceptor and check if you are getting expire message or any flag, then get a refresh token from cookies and ask for access token and reinitiate your request.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this outside of a component?  The react-cookie package uses hooks which cannot be used outside of components.  I have it working with localstorage but want to use cookies instead.

Answer (score 2):

LoL, you can use cookies outside of the component, do console `document.cookie` or if you want to go with npm then use `js-cookie` or `universal-cookie`.

```js
const cookies = document.cookie;
console.log(cookies)
```

Due to `security` reasons, SO not allowing to use `cookie` inside the snippet but it will work fine in your computer.